# how do i get formik to update an input on click?

Tags: reactjs, formik

So i have a formik form, and im setting one of the inputs values with this.state.

This works fine when the page renders. However, i have a click event that changes that state to a new value, but the input value is not updating. How do i do that?

code:

```
this.state.address_1:'test'


initialValues={{
    address_1: this.state.address_1,
}}



<span className='form-cell-wrapper'>
<label>Address Line 1</label>
<Field
name='address_1'
type='text'
style={{
    borderColor:
        errors.address_1 && touched.address_1 && "tomato"
}}
/>
</span>

    addressClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({ 'address_1': 'test 2' });
        console.log('address change', this.state.address_1);


    }
```

Comment: you can use formik's `setFieldValue` function to update the state value of the form

Comment: do you want you to need onchnfe the value in falid  upadte value

Comment: not sure i understand how to use setfieldvalue, and theres no documentation that i can find scouring google.

Answer (score 1):

look add in the filed

```
<Field
onChange={this.addressClick}
value={this .state.address_1}
name='address_1'
type='text'
style={{
    borderColor:
        errors.address_1 && touched.address_1 && "tomato"
}}
/>
and 
addressClick = (e) => {

        this.setState({ 'address_1': e.target.value });
        console.log('address change', this.state.address_1);


    }
```

try it if don't work tell me in commit

Comment: this input needs to be available to type into, but if you use the addressClick, populate it with the state value instead. this is an address lookup function, that when you select an address from the api call, populates the inputs with that data.

Comment: and it didnt work. A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled.

Comment: Mohammed_Alreai the solution work for adding the data to the input, but now you cant type anything into the input in general.